# How is this parameter being passed to the listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
use strict;

var fs = require('fs);

var readable = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt', {encoding: 'utf8', highwaterMark: 32 * 1024 });

readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log(chunk.length)
});
```

If I understand correctly, in node, the readable stream inherits from EventEmitter, which allows it to make use of the listener / .on method.

But, how does the callback : , function(chunk){ console.log(chunk.length)} know the value of the chunk parameter?

Comment: The `.on` method calls the callback internally and passes `chunk` to it.

Comment: okay, I think I understand. So, just to be clear: When the listener detects the 'data' event, it then calls: fs.createReadStream( ) and the chunk parameter, is the value of both parameters listed within that function : (__dirname + '/greet.txt', {encoding: 'utf8', highwaterMark: 32 * 1024 })  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your comment, no, the listener doesn't detect or call anything. It's the other way around, `fs.createReadStream()` is an event emitter. `readable.on('data', function() { ... })` means "readable, please call this function when you emit 'data' event". *readable* emits data events when it has data to "give", calls all registered listeners (only `function(chunk)` in your example) and provides the parameters like detailed in the doc.

Comment: Yeah, on further research i figured it out. The 'data' event is triggered every time the buffer is filled. Each time this event fires, the 'chunk' is the contents of the buffer. Let me know if there are any inaccuracies in this statement. Thx.

Comment: Your statement is correct. I took a shortcut in the explanation for clarity, actually the listeners call are queued in something called Event Loop, there is a good video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

EventEmitter instance has a method called "emit", so somewhere inside the fs readstream, it is called like this

```
emitter.emit('data', chunk);
```

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners

Comment: More technically, it probably does `this.emit('data', chunk);` since the stream IS an `eventEmitter`.